# Class attributes not being inherited

Tags: css

I have to place a css class i've made called "borderless" to every item inside my unordered list, through inheritence I thought if I place it at the top layer it would apply to all its children, but it's not.

I want this example

```
          <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item borderless"">
                <i class="devicon-python-plain ""></i> Hello Stackoverflow
              </li>
    </ul>
```

To apply borderless to all children such as

```
          <ul class="list-group borderless">
              <li class="list-group-item"">
                <i class="devicon-python-plain ""></i> Hello Stackoverflow
              </li>
          </ul>
```

Is this not how inheritance works for css?

css

```
.borderless {
    border-top: 0 none;
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the actual CSS

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule should get you the desired result:

```
.borderless .list-group-item {
    border: none;
}
```

FYI, classes aren't inherited by children, they're just used to tag nodes in HTML which you can then target with CSS selectors and apply certain styles to them. To better understand how styles are inherited from parents to children you need to read about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: "classes aren't inherited by children" is true, but the styles from the classes are, so it may not be necessary to do it as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

To have the attribute values inherited from its parent you have to tell the CSS to do it so.

```
.borderless li{
    border: inherit;
}
```

Or give it a wildcard if you want to apply for all elements inside `.borderless` by using the `*` selector:

```
.borderless * {
    border: inherit;
}
```

See CSS `*` selector docs https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp

```css
ul li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.borderless {
    border-top: 0 none;
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.borderless li{
    border: inherit;
}
```

```html
with .borderless class:
<ul class="list-group borderless">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
  </ul>
  without .borderless:
  <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i> Hello Stackoverflow
      </li>
  </ul>
```